# 200 on a token expiry - correct?

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I have written an implementation of a JWT based authorizer. If there is no JWT, it works as expected and throws a 401.

I have a custom provider which is based off of :

```
AuthProvider, IAuthWithRequest, IAuthPlugin.
```

`TokenException` is being correctly thrown but the response that bubbles up from that is a 200 with a body of

> Error: TokenException: Token has expired

not a 401.

Have I implemented something incorrectly, or is this the intended status code to be returned? If it is intended, is there any way to alter this to a 401 return in my implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the culprate. Was modifying the httpres on Unhandled error exceptions. Removing this rewrite solved the issue and 401 is thrown again.

```
    private void UnhandledExceptionsLogging(IRequest httpreq, IResponse httpres, string operationname, Exception ex)
        {
            ...
            httpres.Write($"Error: {ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
            httpres.EndRequest(skipHeaders: true);
        }
```